# Automorphisms of power set lattice mod finite

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, descriptive-set-theory, lattice-theory

Let $N$ be a countably infinite set and let $\mathcal P$ denote power set.
I get that the automorphisms of $(\mathcal P(N),\subseteq)$ are all induced by permutations of $N$.

But what can be said about automorphisms of $\mathcal P(N)$ mod finite? That is, mod out by the equivalence relation $A\sim B\iff A$ and $B$ differ only finitely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is known as Rudin-Shelah problem. Note that, by Stone duality, this is equivalent to determine the self-homeomorphism group of the Stone-Cech boundary of $N$. Notably, consider the group induced by bijections between two cofinite subsets of $N$ (modulo cofinite coincidence). It maps homomorphically injectively into the automorphism group of $A=\mathcal{P}(N)/\mathrm{fin}$. The problem is whether this map $\Phi$ is surjective, i.e., is every automorphism induced by a bijection between two cofinite subsets.

Using basic model theory Rudin (1956) proved that the continuum hypothesis (CH) implies that the automorphism group of $A$ has cardinal $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$, so $\Phi$ is far from surjective. Shelah (1982) showed the consistency of ZFC + ($\Phi$ is surjective).

See van Douwen's 1990 (posthumous) paper: "The automorphism group of $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/\mathrm{fin}$ need not be simple". In notes of this article, it is mentioned that under CH, this group (thus of cardinal $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$) is simple, and attributed to Rubin-Štěpánek (reference Handbook of boolean algebras, vol 2, 1989) .

Comment: Thanks a lot! Interestingly Google reports *No results found for "rudin-shelah problem"* (well, before you posted this answer)

Comment: PS the simplicity result was also obtained by S. Fuchino, Archive for Mathematical Logic 1992, Volume 31, Issue 5, pp 319-330, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01627505, which provides additional valuable references.

Comment: Oh, I got used to refer to this as "Rudin-Shelah problem", then forgot that I possibly coined this practical formulation :)